# Can be used an expression in the name of variable for reading it in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

```
#In Tclsh
% set n 3
3
% set A$n 15
15
% puts $A3
15
```

But how could I read `$A3` as about like ${A{$n}}
Itried:

```
% puts $[puts \$A$n]
$A3
$
%
```

**I clarify my question**   date:10Aug2022 (UTC 09.14)

In Bash I can do a deeper indirection as like this:

```
a=b;b=5;eval echo $`echo $a`  # output: 5 is good
```

How can I do it in Tcl with `puts` command instead of `set` command as like this:

```
set a b;set b 5;eval {puts [puts \$$a]}   # it has wrong output: $b rather than 5
```

Macleod showed that the `set` command with only one argument is a workaround of a deeper indirection.
That is why the next line is good:

```
set a b;set b 5;eval puts $[set a]  # Output: 5  as required is good
```

So my question is:
In the above Tcl line how can I replace the `set` command with `puts` command and do a deeper indirection in Tcl as like in Bash.
/echo in Bash is as like puts in Tcl/
My question is not for a practical purpose, but for understanding the  parsing, substitution in Tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with just:

```
puts [set A$n]
```

Comment: @Macleod,Thanks your solution really works.
Now I see the `set` can work with one arg. and in case it returns with value.But in case of `puts` command should be using an extra $ prefix. Is there a solution with `puts` also?

Comment: The obvious `puts $[set A$n]` not work? But it's conventional to put a backslash in front of the first `$` there to indicate no substitution: `puts \$[set A$n]`

Comment: @Fellows I have commented above that `puts [set A$n]` works.
and I accepted the Macleod's answer but I would have more question
I clarified this question above, pls. see and advise.

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi, the fundamental difference is that Tcl only does one round of variable substitution before executing a command.  Bash on the other hand will substitute repeatedly until there is nothing more that can be substituted.  Tcl people feel that its method is more predictable and controllable.  The Tcl substitution rules are documented at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.html .

Answer (score 0):

I have read the Tcl man about substitution process and I have made some experiments.

The `puts` command unusable for command substitution according to the next examples.

```
% set x 1; set x [puts 2]; puts "x: >$x<"
x: ><
% set x 1; set x [puts -nonewline 2]; puts "\nx: >$x<"
x: ><
% set x 1; set x [expr 2]; puts "x: >$x<"; # But expr cmd ok of course.
x: >2<
```

( In Bash the echo command is good for command substitution eg.: a=`echo "apple tree"` )

I checked more type of deeper indirect addressing of variable, here is my experiments:
Now let the names of var is numbers.

```
% set 1 2; set 2 3; set 3 4;  #Here is the chain of var
% puts [set [set [set 1]]];   #Command substitution only
4
% puts [expr $[expr $[expr $[expr 1]]]]; #Command and variable substitution
4
```

Now let the names of var is alphas and change the `expr` command to the `string trim` as a dummy string
expression command.

```
% set a b; set b c; set c d ;      # Here is the chain of var
% puts [set [set [set a]]] ;       # Command substitution only
d
# Command and variable substitution:
% puts [eval string trim $[eval string trim $[eval string trim $[string trim a]]]] 
d
```

I would like to know why I had to use `eval` command unlike in case when the names of var were numbers
and `expr` command was enough.
In spite of there were deep (indirect) **var** (and command) **substitution** was in both two cases  .
So it is looks like that deep command substitution controlled by brackets while deep (indirect) var substitution
controlled by `eval` often.

Likewise in Bash the deep var substituting also happens with `eval` command, e.g.:

```
a=b; b=c; c=d   # Here is the chain of var
eval echo \$$(eval echo \$$(eval echo \$a))
d
```